Problem with automatic disabling body scrolling when Select is open, where this setting cannot be changed. shadcn ui
I'm talking about Select here.I've run into a problem where I can't remove the automatic scroll lock when opening a menu. The documentation didn't say anything about this thing and its setting. I tried for a couple of days at least some option to disable the scroll lock and the only option was to remove the use. In the end I had to get into the root of the radix library and disable its use. Please make it possible to disable this function through props or any other implementation. Maybe I'm wrong and there is an add-on, hint if it really exists.
I tried for a couple of days at least some option to disable the scroll lock and the only option was to remove the use. In the end I had to get into the root of the radix library and disable its use. Please make it possible to disable this function through props or any other implementation.
